# How to merge two dataframes that have different column names

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Ok so, I have two dataframes, for the purpose of my question I'm just going to use dummy data

```
df1:
Decimal.hour  Temp  Depth   Salinity 
4.1           10     -3        34
4.2           10     -3.2      33
4.5           9      -3.1      33
4.6           9      -3.2      34
4.7           10     -3.3      34
6.2           15     -3.1      32 
6.4           15     -3.2      32
6.6           14     -3        33
6.7           14     -3        32
7.0           11     -3.1      33
7.1           12     -3.1      33     
7.2           12     -3.1      33
7.4           11     -3.3      34

df2:
Decimal.hour  Run   Transect  Site   Phase   Count   Age 
4.1            1       2        1      1       12     1
4.2            1       2        1      1        3     1
4.5            2       1        2      1        4     1     
4.6            2       1        2      1        10    1
4.7            1       2        1      1        5     6
6.6            3       1        1      1        7     2             
6.7            3       1        1      1        2     1
6.8            3       2        2      1        10    1
6.9            3       2        2      1        9     1
7.0            4       1        2      1        2     1
7.1            4       1        2      1        2     1
7.2            4       2        1      1        6     1
7.3            4       2        1      1        5     2
```

how would i then combine these two dataframes to give me the following data frame? (this is my ideal output)

```
df3:
Decimal.hour  Temp  Depth   Salinity  Run   Transect  Site   Phase   Count   Age 
4.1           10     -3        34      1       2        1      1       12     1
4.2           10     -3.2      33      1       2        1      1        3     1
4.5           9      -3.1      33      2       1        2      1        4     1 
4.6           9      -3.2      34      2       1        2      1        10    1
4.7           10     -3.3      34      1       2        1      1        5     6
6.2           15     -3.1      32      NA      NA       NA     NA       NA    NA
6.4           15     -3.2      32      NA      NA       NA     NA       NA    NA
6.6           14     -3        33      3       1        1      1        7     2 
6.7           14     -3        32      3       1        1      1        2     1
6.8           NA      NA       NA      3       2        2      1        10    1
6.9           NA      NA       NA      3       2        2      1        9     1
7.0           11     -3.1      33      4       1        2      1        2     1
7.1           12     -3.1      33      4       1        2      1        2     1
7.2           12     -3.1      33      4       2        1      1        6     1
7.3           NA.     NA.      NA      4       2        1      1        5     2
7.4           11     -3.3      34      4       2        1      1        5     2
```

So as you can see, both of those data frames have the same column (Decimal.hour), so I was looking for a way to combine them in such a way that the Decimal.hour values would match up and then NA values would be inputted when certain rows didn't have any data.

I looked around and found this code here that people said would work:

```
dfNew<-dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

however, what it gave me was the decimal column merging but then the second dataframe just having all NA values.

I also tried:

```
smartbind(df1, df2)
```

but it gave me the same issue, with df2 having all NA values.

I'm wondering if anyone could give me some help on solving this as the dataframe I actually have has 2160 rows and 4 columns for df1 and 485 rows and 36 columns for df2, so need some assistance in understanding why my merging is'nt going correctly. I've never had to merge these types of uneven dataframes before hence why I'm struggling.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by="Decimal.hour")
```

May be useful in the future: https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: waw Mr.Zen, you have just gave me a solution so quickly thank you so much. I've been struggling for the past 3 hours trying to look around for a solution before asking on here. I will for sure save the pdf link. Thanks so much again!

Comment: I do have an question, if you don't mind adding on if you know why this is happening. After i have used that code, they have combined sucessfully, however instead of NA values being there, it is as if R has just generated or duplicate numbers, meaning now when I add up the "Count" column extra numebrs have been added on. For example, the the total count for df1 is 30, but when I merge df1 with df2, the count now becomes 40, even though df2 does not have a count column. Why would this be happening?

Comment: Most likely because `Decimal.hour` has duplicate values. If the rows `Decimal.hour` are not unique, then it's not possible to merge uniquely and `left_join` will duplicate rows (e.g. if you have more than one instance of `4.1`).

Comment: Ah ok i see, so would there be another way around that? As I'm basically just needing the 3 columns in df2 added on to df1, but matched by the "Decimal hours" column, thus avoiding dublications and instead say having NA values in the cell instead

Answer (score 0):

A base R option is using `merge`

```
merge(df1, df2, by="Decimal.hour", all = TRUE)
```